# How to get constant pool table with javassist

Tags: java, javassist

How can we get the constant pool table from the class file using javassist?

I have written the code till here:

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
pool.insertClassPath(filepath);
CtClass cc = pool.get(filename);
```

Now please, please tell me the further steps.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the CtClass you just need to access the classFile object to retrieve the constant pool, like the following:

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault(); 
pool.insertClassPath(filepath); 
CtClass cc = pool.get(filename);
ConstPool classConstantPool = cc.getClassFile().getConstPool()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles here, it can be done in a more efficient way (without using a `ClassPool`):

```
try (InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(filepath))) {
  return new ClassFile(new DataInputStream(inputStream)).getConstPool();
}
```

---

If performance is really important, it can be optimized so that only the constant pool is read from the file:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(filepath))) {
  return readConstantPool(new DataInputStream(inputStream));
}
```

where:

```
// copied from ClassFile#read(DataInputStream)
private static ConstPool readConstantPool(@NonNull DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
  int magic = in.readInt();
  if (magic != 0xCAFEBABE) {
    throw new IOException("bad magic number: " + Integer.toHexString(magic));
  }

  int minor = in.readUnsignedShort();
  int major = in.readUnsignedShort();
  return new ConstPool(in);
}
```