# how to get a list of constant mappings in the java class constant pool?

Tags: java, clojure, java-bytecode-asm

when I run `javap -c Address.class > Address.txt` on a particular class,

I get a bunch of output, with `#<NUMBER>` as the index to the constant pool

```
Compiled from "Address.java"
public class test.Address extends test.Entity {
  public test.Address();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method test/DefaultEntity."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0       
       5: aconst_null   
       6: putfield      #2                  // Field io:Ljava/lang/String;
       9: aload_0       
      10: aconst_null   
      11: putfield      #3                  // Field zip4:Ljava/lang/String;
      14: aload_0       
      15: aconst_null   
      16: putfield      #4                  // Field zip:Ljava/lang/String;
      19: aload_0
```

How would I be able to get the pool in the form of a hashmap? i.e:

```
{1  "Method test/DefaultEntity."<init>":()"
 2   "Field io:Ljava/lang/String;"}
```

Comment: The constant pool is at the top of the output of `javap -c -verbose YourClass`.

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically get it? I was looking at asm but couldn't find the method

Comment: You can use [BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) to parse the [Constant Pool](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/classfile/ConstantPool.html) from the [class file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html).

Comment: I was hoping to just be able to use included asm library for clojune.

Comment: If you just want to inspect code you can use: https://github.com/gtrak/no.disassemble

Comment: Looks like no.disassemble uses instrumentation and Eclipse JDT.

Comment: If you can live with using java libraries, you can look at this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267267/how-to-get-constant-pool-table-with-javassist. I have used JavaAssist before and its pretty nice.

Comment: With ASM you normally don’t need to deal with the constant pool as the library does that for you, e.g. if you [visit a field instruction](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitFieldInsn(int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) you will already get the names and type descriptor extracted from the constant pool. This applies to all instructions with references to the constant pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), you can use a [ClassReader](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html) to read a .class file and then use getItemCount() and the various read methods to read all of the constant pool items.

```
(def cr (clojure.asm.ClassReader "test.Address"))
(.getItemCount cr) 
;; etc
```